# Parse HTML tag from RSS CDATA

Tags: jquery, html, json, xml-parsing, rss

I want to ask if I can parse out the tags from CDATA tag in RSS?

I have used a basic jquery function to get the JSON object from the RSS, here is my code:

```
 $.get("someURL", function(data) {
            console.log('InGet');
            var $xml = $(data);
            $xml.find("item").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    item = {
                        title: $this.find("title").text(),
                        link: $this.find("link").text(),
                        description: $this.find("description").text(),                        
                        pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                        author: $this.find("author").text()
                }
            });
        });
```

Now I want to get the html tags from the CDATA inside the description, but seems find() is not working to item.description.

Here is a simple structure for the RSS

```
<item>
  <description>
      <![CDATA[<img .....> some content<div>...</div>]<br><br> some content]>
  </description>
</item>
```

So is any way I can parse the CDATA like we did the normal way with those xml tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jQuery.

```
description: $( $this.find("description").text() )
```

Comment: So this will return a normal jquery object? description: $( $this.find("description").text() ). find("some tag") seems not work for me either

Comment: If `<description>` contains CDATA then `$this.find("description").text()` will return the actual text - i.e. an HTML string. Which you can pass to jQuery to parse it. What does `console.log($this.find("description").text())` output?

Comment: Of course you need to use `$xml = $.parseXML(data)` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)). I missed that one.